# How to make Gmail separate each email item instead of bunding into a conversation?

Tags: gmail

I've been forced to use Gmail by my new employer. My old employer also used Gmail but the POP3 option was available to I consume that via Outlook.

The employer has locked the POP3 option so I've no choice but to struggle with the conversations, threads, labels system in Gmail.

Is there some way to make it work like old-skool email with Sent Items and each incoming/response a separate email item, most recent at the top?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can turn off conversation view in the settings. It's on the "General" tab.

You can treat labels like folders; just "move" your messages to a label rather than "add" a label.